# Loop changes data of rows not even looped through?

Tags: python, loops, pandas

I have a `vocabulary`, which is a list of words. I have a dataframe `posts` with two columns, `words` and `wordsdictcoded`. First one contains a list of words like `['this', 'is']`. The vocabulary contains all the words that appear in the `words` column.
The `wordsdictcoded` column should contain the words encoded. The coding works like this: each word is represented by an array of 0s and 1s in the length of the vocabulary. The `words` column is encoded by the vocabulary: if  the `words` nth word is the ith in the vocabulary, the encoding's ith element will be a 1. 
Fe.:

```
vocabulary = ['this', 'is' 'a', 'test']
words[i] = ['a', 'test']
wordsdictcoded[i] = [0, 0, 1, 1]
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve. My code is:

```
listofzeros = [0] * len(vocabulary)
posts['wordsdictcoded'] = [listofzeros] * len(posts)
for i in range(0, len(posts)):
    for word in posts['words'][i]:
        posts['wordsdictcoded'][i][vocabulary.index(word)] = 1
```

However, I end up with all 1's for every row of posts['wordsdictcoded']. I don't get it. If I just run the loop for `range(0,1)` even then `print(posts['wordsdictcoded'][5]` gets the value, all rows get the value. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it has been said in the other answer, your problem is with the `*` operator creating another reference to the *same* list. A possible solution would be to force Python create multiple distinct lists:

```
posts['wordsdictcoded'] = [[0] * len(vocabulary) for _ in range(len(posts))]
```

Comment: Thank you, but this makes `[[0, 0, 0, 0]]` instead of `[0, 0, 0, 0]`.

Comment: My mistake. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

That's a common python gotcha. The problem is that `[listofzeros] * len(posts)` copies the same list `len` times, it does not create copies. You can test that

```
id(posts['wordsdictcoded'][0]) == id(posts['wordsdictcoded'][1])
```

See comment below (by user `DYZ`) for solution

Comment: So each time I update one, all of them are updated? Why would it work like that? GOSH. How can I circumvent this? I just need to make those all 0d out, but then changing them individually.

Comment: @lte__ that's *ALWAYS* how things work in Python. Everything is an object, and variable names are references to objects. Also, assignment *never* copies.